Cleaning up bubbles/imperfections in mesh for printing 3D scanned statues
I have a custom statue and sculpture business, and just recently expanded from life-sized sculpting by hand to 3D scanning and printing. Blender has been a godsend in cleaning up and editing the scans.
A problem I keep running into is needing several days to carefully remove individual bubbles/imperfections scattered all over the statues. These bubbles appear on either side of the mesh (basically right on top of the person's skin, or right under it on the inside of the hollow statue), and are sometimes intertwined with the what should be the single correct layer of mesh where the person's skin is. I'll attach some photos of individual bubbles. Some are taken from inside the statue, some are on the outside surface of the statue. Sometimes it comes down to deleting these 3D bubbles one vertex at a time. It's not always as simple as lasso selecting the entire affected area on X-ray and deleting it, then selecting the loop along the edge of the hole and filling it in. For example, imagine if this cloud of bubbles is intertwined with the area around someone's eyes or fingers. I can't delete the area of what should be the single layer of skin, so I have to painstakingly go through and carefully delete all these tiny extra pieces on the outside of the skin and under the skin.
Please tell me there is a way to more quickly simplify the mesh to a single continuous layer, just in the areas with these bubbles.
I don't want to decimate the whole statue, because I need the detail when printing it out.
And I have quite a decent 3D scanner, and am at least above average if not advanced with using it. When you're 3D scanning a person's entire body and they're breathing and trying to hold still, little tiny imperfections happen sometimes. I'm sure if I got a $30k scanner to capture an entire body in 5 seconds, that would be great, but it's just not in the budget.
Anyway, I'd be so grateful if anyone has ideas for how to streamline this process so it's not days and days of bubble removal.


This seems to be related to sharp edges, so, you could try this method:

In edit mode, go to the "select" menu to select sharp edges (adjust the angle that will appear in a box)



With the sharp edges selected, ctrl+e and "mark seam" (The sharp edges will become red)

Now, select one vertice/edge/face on the bubble

Press ctrl+L (select linked) and select the "seam" option.


This will very probably select the entire bubble at once so you can delete.
Another hint, you could try to "dissolve" (ctrl+x) the bubble instead of deleting. This will leave a face so you don't have to create another one. (But if you need that it is made of a pattern instead of a single face, then do what you're used to)

Thank you so much for trying to help. I thought this was going to solve at least 70% of my issue, because you're right that these bubbles often have sharp edges around them, and nowhere else on the statues has that. I can get it to select the seams along the bubble edges, but when I select a vertice on the bubble and ctrl+L, basically the entire statue lights up. I think the bubbles are too intertwined with the surface of the statue. It would be more helpful if the bubbles were neatly disonnected.
Not sure if this is allowed, but could I possibly send you a file and have you look at it?

@MarieStacey, if everything gets selected (you must click seam!), this means that the seam has a hole in it, it's not a cloosed loop. If you can identify the hole, you can select the missing edges and mark seam to close the seam loop.

Yeah, the bubbles are rarely perfect enough to be a neat loop. They're so numerous and interconnected with the skin's surface. I guess I have to delete them all the slow way. Thanks anyway.

@MarieStacey Have you ever tried to use the "smooth" brush in sculpt mode?

Yeah, it helps a tiny bit, but definitely doesn't solve the bubbles.
